# How to display a DataTable data in Windows Phone 7 in a tabular format?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I have a DataTable object in C#.Net with 50 rows and 10 columns.I want to display this data in Windows Phone.Is there any control in Windows Phone which takes the data from a DataTable source and displays it ?And user should be able to see the 10 columns data of each record.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific table control for this, but you can create a manual table using grids with column and row definitions and bind them to your data in view-model